# Proof that $ y(n) = ∑_{k=-∞}^{∞}\ {a}^{-k}u(n-k)u(-k) = \frac{1}{1-a }$ if $n>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, exponential-sum

Can someone explain the steps and how the boundaries for the summation change to result in the answer (And possible for the case where $n\leq 0$. I am not really a mathematician, don't know if the question is clear( this question comes from finding the impulse response of an LTI system )

The full equation is

$$ y(n) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} {a}^{-k}u(-k)u(n-k) = \frac{1}{1-a} $$

if $n>0$ where $u(n)$ is the unit step function.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Derivation

Comment: There is no $n$ in the sum, and the sum seems to diverge since for negative $k$ the terms get large. The last thing on the right in the title is unreadable but contains other symbols than $k$ and $n$.

Comment: Thanks for the Link. Didn't know what to search for @labbhattacharjee

Comment: @coffeemath. I have updated the question. Was in a hurry to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of the step-functions (assuming $u$ is the [Heaviside step-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)) $u(-k)u(n-k)$ is non-zero only if $-k\geq 0$ and $n-k\geq 0$, that is if $n\geq k$ and $k\leq 0$. If $n > 0$ then this is the case for all negative $k$ so the sum becomes (assuming $|a|<1$)

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a^{-k}u(-k)u(n-k) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^0 a^{-k} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a^{k} = \frac{1}{1-a} $$

where in the second to last equality I switched the summation index $k\to -k$ and in the last equality I used that the sum of a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) $1+x+x^2+\ldots = \frac{1}{1-x}$ if $|x|<1$.